# /bin/aem/test.MY_SELECTOR.json is giving forbidden access message

Tags: aem, aem-6

when appending .json at the end of the path to the sling servlet  http://:/bin/aem/test.MY_SELECTOR.json or similar ajax call, I get 403 forbidden access error on the page.

however, if I use: http://:/bin/aem/test.MY_SELECTOR.now
or any other string after the (.)dot, it works without issues.

Only .json seems to be the issue.

Is there something blocking from ACS commons.

Comment: can you paste your servlet code here?

Comment: is the selector a number ?

Comment: no it is not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert jsonResponse, which is a String to Gson.toJson(jsonResponse)